# EF Core Include navigation property on abstract derived class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm getting the following exception thrown when attempting to include a navigation property for a derived type:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid include.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.PopulateIncludeTree(IncludeTreeNode includeTreeNode, Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.ProcessInclude(NavigationExpansionExpression source, Expression expression, Boolean thenInclude)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   ...
```

Using the following simplified class structure:

```
public abstract class BaseJob
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
public abstract class WorkerJob : BaseJob
{
  public Person Person { get; set; }
}
public class PaintingJob : WorkerJob
{
  public string Color { get; set; }
}
public class Person {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When querying via the `DbContext` as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#include-on-derived-types):

```
// Throws InvalidOperationException
var jobs = await _context.BaseJobs
  .Include(job => (job as WorkerJob).Person) // WorkerJob is abstract
  .ToListAsync();
```

This must be related to the navigation property existing on an abstract class as adjusting the query to the following works as intended:

```
// Works as intended
var jobs = await _context.BaseJobs
  .Include(job => (job as PaintingJob).Person) // PaintingJob is concrete
  .ToListAsync();
```

However, I have many concrete derived classes and I don't want to have to change the query every time a new concrete class is added. Could this be a bug with EF Core, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely not a bug, the error was mine. I had misconfigured the context as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PaintingJob>(entity =>
  {
    entity.HasBaseType<WorkerJob>();
    entity.HasOne(x => x.Person)
      .WithMany()
      .HasForeignKey(x => x.PersonId);
  });
```

Changing this to use the abstract class when defining the navigation property resolves the exception being thrown and returns results as expected.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<WorkerJob>(entity =>
  {
    entity.HasBaseType<BaseJob>();
    entity.HasOne(x => x.Person)
      .WithMany()
      .HasForeignKey(x => x.PersonId);
  });
```